# Need Help populating Lead ID into DE after Cloud Page Form Submission

Tags: marketing-cloud, html, cloudpage

I created a Cloud Pages form in Marketing Cloud and everything is working properly for form entries. It looks at the lead object and if that email is linked to a lead, it updates the lead with the form values. If no email exists in the leads object, it creates a new lead with all the form values. I want to take those form values and add it to a Data Extension, along with that Lead ID. I created a Data Extension called "InterestsWeb" and mapped all the DE field names to the form values. The issue is that I cannot get the ID value to populate into that "InterestsWeb" SubscriberKey field. It keeps throwing an error on submission. I think it's because I'm referencing the @leadId value before the form requests it. I tried moving the @insert function lower in the form but that did not work.

```ampscript
%%[
IF RequestParameter("submitted") == true THEN
var @Newsletter, @MobileFleet, @FleetService, @Allison, @DetroitDiesel, @TICO, @Carrier, @Parts, @insert 

Set @Newsletter = iif(RequestParameter('Newsletter')==true,'true','false')
Set @MobileFleet = iif(RequestParameter('MobileFleet')==true,'true','false')
Set @FleetService = iif(RequestParameter('FleetService')==true,'true','false')
Set @Allison = iif(RequestParameter('Allison')==true,'true','false')
Set @DetroitDiesel = iif(RequestParameter('DetroitDiesel')==true,'true','false')
Set @TICO = iif(RequestParameter('TICO')==true,'true','false')
Set @Carrier = iif(RequestParameter('Carrier')==true,'true','false')
Set @Parts = iif(RequestParameter('Parts')==true,'true','false')

Set @insert = InsertData ("InterestsDE", 
    "SubscriberKey", @leadId,
     "FirstName", RequestParameter("firstname"),
      "LastName", RequestParameter("lastname"),
      "Company", RequestParameter("company"),
      "Email", RequestParameter("email"),
      "Newsletter", @Newsletter,
      "MobileFleet", @MobileFleet,
      "FleetService", @FleetService,
      "Allison", @Allison,
      "DetroitDiesel", @DetroitDiesel,
      "TICO", @TICO,
      "Carrier", @Carrier,
      "Parts", @Parts,
      "Other", RequestParameter("Other")
          )   

/* check if lead already exists */

  SET @subscriberRows = RetrieveSalesforceObjects(
   "Lead",
   "Id,Email",
   "Email", "=", RequestParameter("email")
   )
  
  /* get lead id if lead exists */
  
  IF RowCount(@subscriberRows) > 0 THEN 
  SET @leadId = Field(Row(@subscriberRows, 1), "Id")
  
  /* update existing lead */
  SET @updateRecord = UpdateSingleSalesforceObject(
      "Lead", @leadId,
      "FirstName", RequestParameter("firstname"),
      "LastName", RequestParameter("lastname"),
      "Company", RequestParameter("company"),
      "Newsletter__c", @Newsletter,
      "Mobile_Fleet__c", @MobileFleet,
      "Fleet_Service__c", @FleetService,
      "Allison__c", @Allison,
      "Detroit_Diesel__c", @DetroitDiesel,
      "TICO__c", @TICO,
      "Carrier__c", @Carrier,
      "Parts__c", @Parts,
      "Other__c", RequestParameter("Other")      
     )

  ELSE
   /* create a new lead */

  SET @leadId = CreateSalesforceObject(
        "Lead", 13,
        "FirstName", RequestParameter("firstname"),
        "LastName", RequestParameter("lastname"),
        "Company", RequestParameter("company"),
        "Email", RequestParameter("email"),
      "Newsletter__c", @Newsletter,
      "Mobile_Fleet__c", @MobileFleet,
      "Fleet_Service__c", @FleetService,
      "Allison__c", @Allison,
      "Detroit_Diesel__c", @DetroitDiesel,
      "TICO__c", @TICO,
      "Carrier__c", @Carrier,
      "Parts__c", @Parts,
      "Other__c", RequestParameter("Other")      
     )
 
             
  ENDIF       
]%% 
<h2>Thank you for submitting the form.</h2>

%%[ ELSE ]%%


<table style="padding: 20px;"><tr><td>
      <h2>Please tell us about your interests!</h2>
      <form action="%%=RequestParameter('PAGEURL')=%%" method="post">
        
         <label>First Name: </label><input type="text" name="firstname" required=""><br><br> 
        
         <label>Last Name: </label><input type="text" name="lastname" required=""><br><br> 
        <label>Company: </label><input type="text" name="company" required=""><br><br>        
        <label>Email: </label><input type="text" name="email" required=""><br><br>
        
        <label>Newsletter: </label><input type="checkbox" name="Newsletter" value="true"><br><br>
        
        <label>Mobile Fleet: </label><input type="checkbox" name="MobileFleet" value="true"><br><br>
        <label>Fleet Service: </label><input type="checkbox" name="FleetService" value="true"><br><br>
        
         <label>Allison: </label><input type="checkbox" name="Allison" value="true"><br><br>
        
         <label>Detroit Diesel: </label><input type="checkbox" name="DetroitDiesel" value="true"><br><br>
        
        <label>TICO: </label><input type="checkbox" name="TICO" value="true"><br><br>
        
        <label>Carrier: </label><input type="checkbox" name="Carrier" value="true"><br><br>
        
        <label>Parts: </label><input type="checkbox" name="Parts" value="true"><br><br>
        
        <label>Other: </label><input type="text" name="Other"><br><br>

     
       <input name="submitted" type="hidden" value="true"><br>
         <input type="submit" value="Submit">
      </form>  
</td></tr></table>

%%[ ENDIF ]%%
```

Comment: Your first insert -- you're referencing `@leadId` before it's set.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest outputting your variable values at the top for debugging purposes -- that'll get you going in the right direction.

Also you need to retrieve the `leadId` before you use it in your insert.

```ampscript
%%[ set @debug = 1  ]%%

%%[ IF RequestParameter("submitted") == true THEN ]%%

  %%[

    set @firstname = RequestParameter("firstname")
    set @lastname =  RequestParameter("lastname")
    set @company =  RequestParameter("company")
    set @email =  RequestParameter("email")
    set @Other =  RequestParameter("Other")
    Set @Newsletter = iif(RequestParameter('Newsletter')==true,'true','false')
    Set @MobileFleet = iif(RequestParameter('MobileFleet')==true,'true','false')
    Set @FleetService = iif(RequestParameter('FleetService')==true,'true','false')
    Set @Allison = iif(RequestParameter('Allison')==true,'true','false')
    Set @DetroitDiesel = iif(RequestParameter('DetroitDiesel')==true,'true','false')
    Set @TICO = iif(RequestParameter('TICO')==true,'true','false')
    Set @Carrier = iif(RequestParameter('Carrier')==true,'true','false')
    Set @Parts = iif(RequestParameter('Parts')==true,'true','false')

    SET @subscriberRows = RetrieveSalesforceObjects(
         "Lead",
         "Id,Email",
         "Email", "=", @email
         )    

    if RowCount(@subscriberRows) > 0 then
      SET @leadId = Field(Row(@subscriberRows, 1), "Id")
    else
      set @leadID = 0    
    endif 

    if @debug == 1 then
      output(concat("<br>leadId: ", @leadId))
      output(concat("<br>firstname: ", @firstname))
      output(concat("<br>lastname: ", @lastname))
      output(concat("<br>company: ", @company))
      output(concat("<br>email: ", @email))
      output(concat("<br>other    : ", @other    ))
      output(concat("<br>Newsletter: ", @Newsletter))
      output(concat("<br>MobileFleet: ", @MobileFleet))
      output(concat("<br>FleetService: ", @FleetService))
      output(concat("<br>Allison: ", @Allison))
      output(concat("<br>DetroitDiesel: ", @DetroitDiesel))
      output(concat("<br>TICO: ", @TICO))
      output(concat("<br>Carrier: ", @Carrier))
      output(concat("<br>Parts: ", @Parts))
    endif

    Set @insert = InsertData ("InterestsDE", 
          "SubscriberKey", @leadId,
          "FirstName", @firstname,
          "LastName", @lastname,
          "Company", @company,
          "Email", @email,
          "Newsletter", @Newsletter,
          "MobileFleet", @MobileFleet,
          "FleetService", @FleetService,
          "Allison", @Allison,
          "DetroitDiesel", @DetroitDiesel,
          "TICO", @TICO,
          "Carrier", @Carrier,
          "Parts", @Parts,
          "Other", @Other
          )   

      
    IF @leadID > 0 THEN 

        SET @updateRecord = UpdateSingleSalesforceObject(
            "Lead", @leadId,
            "FirstName", @firstname,
            "LastName", @lastname,
            "Company", @company,
            "Newsletter__c", @Newsletter,
            "Mobile_Fleet__c", @MobileFleet,
            "Fleet_Service__c", @FleetService,
            "Allison__c", @Allison,
            "Detroit_Diesel__c", @DetroitDiesel,
            "TICO__c", @TICO,
            "Carrier__c", @Carrier,
            "Parts__c", @Parts,
            "Other__c", @Other      
           )

    ELSE

        SET @leadId = CreateSalesforceObject(
            "Lead", 13,
            "FirstName", @firstname,
            "LastName", @lastname,
            "Company", @company,
            "Email", @email,
            "Newsletter__c", @Newsletter,
            "Mobile_Fleet__c", @MobileFleet,
            "Fleet_Service__c", @FleetService,
            "Allison__c", @Allison,
            "Detroit_Diesel__c", @DetroitDiesel,
            "TICO__c", @TICO,
            "Carrier__c", @Carrier,
            "Parts__c", @Parts,
            "Other__c", @Other   
           )
    
    ENDIF
               
  ]%% 

  <h2>Thank you for submitting the form.</h2>

%%[ ELSE ]%%


  <table style="padding: 20px;"><tr><td>
    <h2>Please tell us about your interests!</h2>
    <form action="%%=RequestParameter('PAGEURL')=%%" method="post">
      <label>First Name: </label><input type="text" name="firstname" required=""><br><br> 
      <label>Last Name: </label><input type="text" name="lastname" required=""><br><br> 
      <label>Company: </label><input type="text" name="company" required=""><br><br>        
      <label>Email: </label><input type="text" name="email" required=""><br><br>
      <label>Newsletter: </label><input type="checkbox" name="Newsletter" value="true"><br><br>
      <label>Mobile Fleet: </label><input type="checkbox" name="MobileFleet" value="true"><br><br>
      <label>Fleet Service: </label><input type="checkbox" name="FleetService" value="true"><br><br>
      <label>Allison: </label><input type="checkbox" name="Allison" value="true"><br><br>
      <label>Detroit Diesel: </label><input type="checkbox" name="DetroitDiesel" value="true"><br><br>
      <label>TICO: </label><input type="checkbox" name="TICO" value="true"><br><br>
      <label>Carrier: </label><input type="checkbox" name="Carrier" value="true"><br><br>
      <label>Parts: </label><input type="checkbox" name="Parts" value="true"><br><br>
      <label>Other: </label><input type="text" name="Other"><br><br>
      <input name="submitted" type="hidden" value="true"><br>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>  
  </td></tr></table>

%%[ ENDIF ]%%
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. That code was able to pull the leadID into the DE but it's not pulling Sales Cloud. I'll try a few different ways to fix this